# If a propane torch is rated at 200,000 BTUs, what does this translate to in terms of joules/second?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy, power, unit-conversion

If a propane torch is rated at 200,000 [BTU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_thermal_unit)s, what does this translate to in terms of joules/second?

Not exactly a physics question per say, but it falls in the realm. How do I convert/understand these various propane torch ratings in terms of joules or watt output?

One website said the rating is meaning BTUs/Hr, but it didn't say this directly, so I still not sure if this is the correct way to interpret.

Answer (score 2):

As [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_thermal_unit#As_a_unit_of_power) says:

> When used as a unit of power for heating and cooling systems, BTU per hour (BTU/h) is the correct unit, though this is often abbreviated to just "BTU".

So when you see BTU used as a unit of power, they're just being sloppy and you should think instead BTU/hour which would be $0.293 W$.  Your 200000 BTU torch would be $58.6 kW$.

Some conversion sites aren't going to tell you this explicitly, but they will give you the correct conversion factor (such as: http://homeguides.sfgate.com/figure-btus-electric-heater-73701.html or http://www.borino.com/gyc/wattsbtu_calculator.htm).

Answer (score -1):

The British thermal unit (BTU or Btu) is a traditional unit of energy equal to about 1055 joules ([ref](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_thermal_unit)). A propane torch rated at 200,000BTU will contain this amount of energy in total.

The rate at which it supplies this energy is down to how you. In a [propane torch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propane_torch), you can control the rate at which the gas is burned. Or you can burn it [all at once](http://youtu.be/pP3_DxbyJ0E) resulting in an explosion.

Comment: iantresman,

There are many stoves and torches rated at a certain "BTU" do not include any gas sources, you have to supply the gas source (predetermined as propane), this means the manufacturer cannot possibly be referring to the total energy in the gas source which the user must supply.

Here is an example:
http://www.homebrewing.org/18-Propane-Burner--220000-BTU-_p_3214.html

"These burners will top out at a whopping 220,000 BTUs."

So this burner would put out, 232 112 288 joules... per second, per minute, per hour? 

Per hour makes the most sense, but that is still a lot of heat (~65kJ/s)

Comment: You will also often see gas-powered devices that are line fed still rated by "BTU"; which wouldn't make sense for this description as they have a practically unlimited access to it relative to what they consume.

Answer (score -2):

Others have answered correctly but to add some background information from my experience.

BTU output is short for BTU/hour. Also, if your process requirements are strict, do not trust the burner manufactures output numbers. Burners output are dependent on two main variables: fuel type (caloric value) and pressure to burner orifice. Pressure is generally regulated from the tank down to a range between 6 inches water column to 30 PSI. Tank pressure for a 20 lb propane tank can range from 220 PSI at 70 degrees F to zero PSI at -44 F. When propane vaporizes, it requires heat (endothermic reaction) and at lower temperatures the pressure supplied to the burner is diminished.

That being said, I have seen roofing burners for sale rated at a whopping 500,000 BTU/hour that claim they can be connected to a 20 lb propane tank. The problem is that a 20 lb propane can only deliver so many cubic foot of propane gas (2,500 BTU/cubic foot). At 70 degrees F a 20 lb propane tank can only deliver around 90,000 BTU/hour of gas, effectively limiting the 500,000 BTU/hour burner to 90,000 BTU/hour. Even a 100 lb tank can only deliver 300,000 BTU/hour of gas at 70 degrees F.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This seems to address more of the technical side of *using* such burners, rather than the physics of unit conversions that was asked.

Comment: Yes, as was prefaced.

Comment: Okay, so that basically means you haven't posted an *answer* to the question but *side commentary*. As this is a Question & Answer site, we expect answers to actually answer the question asked, hence, the -2 score.